# For android app development, Does flutter needs another language as well?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, kotlin

I,m a beginner to flutter and I'm still referring tutorials so bare with me on that. I'm trying to develop an Android application. I started developing using flutter. Main question I have is does flutter needs another language like Kotlin or java, or just can use alone for android app development. Reasoning is I'm trying to add firestore db, and I saw some documentations provide for Kotlin and java only. So this gives me the question, when developing android applications with flutter, do I need another language.Plus if needed, how to merge both. Currently using vs code, so do I need android studio for that part.

Also if this is a duplicate, feel free to add it here. Because I didn't find answer for this.

Tried reading several articles but didn't get the answer

Comment: When you want to deploy the android app, flutter with automatically build a java/kotlin app that executes your flutter/dart application. You will never need to touch any of that code, apart from maybe the android manifest file. Every app-specific code is written in dart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, when developing Android applications with Flutter, you do not need to use another language like Kotlin or Java. Flutter is a cross-platform framework that allows you to build applications for Android, iOS, web, and desktop using a single codebase.

Flutter has its own programming language called Dart, which is used for writing the application logic, UI components, and integrating various services and APIs. Dart is a modern, object-oriented language that is designed specifically for Flutter.

Regarding your specific question about integrating Firestore, Flutter provides an official Firebase plugin that allows you to easily connect to and interact with Firestore in your Flutter app. The Firebase plugin for Flutter is written in Dart and provides a convenient API for Firestore operations.

You can use the Firebase plugin for Flutter to perform all the necessary Firestore operations like reading and writing data, querying the database, and listening to real-time updates. You do not need to use Kotlin or Java specifically for Firestore integration in a Flutter app.

Answer (score 2):

Only Dart. There is no need to learn Java or Kotlin later on.

Answer (score 1):

A reason to use a different language in Flutter is that you need to write [platform-channel connector](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels) to the underlying OS.

While there are a lot of plugins at [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) that you can take advantage of, if you need to customize plugin behavior or the SDK you want isn't available as a Flutter plugin, you'll have to write your own.

This can also happen with "official" SDK Flutter plugins where the main SDK written in Java/Kotlin/Swift/etc. is updated, the Flutter plugin has not, so either you wait for the plugin maintainers or write your own.

And if you are writing your own plugin, familiarity with the tools/language/APIs of the OS (Android,iOS,Windows,Mac,Linux) is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter uses Dart as development language. To integrate Firestore - use https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Comment: Thanks for that. But I need to know the main question. Can I make android applications only by flutter or need Kotlin or java in the middle of the development.

Comment: Yes, you can. There might be some things which might need platform-specific stuff, but in this case you can use Channel from Flutter

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need Java or Kotlin to use Firestore with Flutter. Flutter offers its own Firebase plugins, including cloud_firestore, that allow you to seamlessly integrate Firestore into your Flutter app using Dart.

Important :

- No need for Android Studio: You can continue using VS Code for development
- Platform Channels (rare cases): If you encounter a very specific feature not yet supported by Flutter's Firestore plugin, you could potentially use platform channels to bridge native Java/Kotlin code for that specific functionality. But this is unlikely to be necessary for most Firestore use cases. Platform channels are very useful when you want to perform platform specific tasks.